# Google Universal Analytics with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I had a problem with Google Analytics code on my responsive site, that I built on Twitter Bootstrap. On the next day after adding the code Google analytics complained, that "Tracking Not installed". I changed the place of code and it started to count my visits. The next day again I saw, that tracking code did not work.
This is regular google-analytics code, named isogram, I changed my stre ID:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: make sure your Account has been upgraded to Universal analytics, if your Google Analytics account is set to classic analytics and you try and use the universal analytics code it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with former analytics code. I changed it with the following code. Now everything is OK:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-1']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();

    </script>
```

Comment: I would advise you to upgrade your account to Universal analytics.

Comment: My google-analytics is already upgraded into universal and it gave me an universal analytics code. But unfortunately this isogram code does not work on my one-page responsive book landing page site. Therefore I did this workaround.